# In Ruby, isn't self.user_name the same as @user_name?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, isn't an instance variable like `@foo` and a class variable, `@@bar`?

In some code, I see a few

```
self.user_name = @name
```

or even

```
a += 1 if name != user_name   # this time, without the "self."
                              # and it is the first line of a method so 
                              # it doesn't look like it is a local variable
```

what is the self for?  I thought it might be an accessor, but then can't it be just user_name instead of self.user_name?  And I don't even see any code to make it an accessor, like `attr_accessor`, and not in the base class either.

Comment: The other answers give a good idea of scope, instance variables, and local scope variables. Read them for a good understanding of the issue, the one thing they've left out is that `self` is a reference to the current 'scope', the ruby equivalent of `this` in other programming languages, when used in an instance method, it references the current instance, when used in a class method, it references that class.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby:

- `@foo` is an instance variable
- `@@bar` is a class variable

Instance and class variables are private by default. It means, you can't set or get the value outside the class or the module itself.

If you want to set a value for `foo`, you need an attribute accessor.

```
class Model
  def foo
    @foo
  end

  def foo=(value)
    @foo = value
  end
end
```

For convenience (and performance reason), this is the same of

```
class Model
  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

Then you can do

```
m = Model.new
m.foo = "value"
```

And within the class you can doo

```
class Model

  # ...

  def something
    self.foo = "value"
    # equivalent to
    @foo = value
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

> what is the self for? I thought it might be an accessor

It's a method at least - probably an accessor. `self.name = something` will call the method `name=` and `self.name`, or if no local variable called `name` exists, just `name` will call the method `name`.

> but then can't it be just user_name instead of self.user_name?

When invoking the `name=` method you need the `self` because `name = something` would just create a local variable called `name`. When invoking the `name` method, it doesn't matter whether you write `name` or `self.name` unless there is also a local variable called `name`.

> And I don't even see any code to make it an accessor, like attr_accessor, and not in the base class either.

If there is no call to `attr_accessor` and no explicit definition of `name` and `name=` anywhere, they might be handled by `method_missing` or defined by a different method than `attr_accessor`.

> isn't self.user_name the same as @user_name

Only if it's defined to be. If you define `user_name` and `user_name=? using`attr_accessor`they will get and set`@user_name`. However if you define them through other means (or manually), they can do whatever you want.

For example ActiveRecord uses `method_missing` to "define" getter and setter methods that correspond to data base columns. So if your ActiveRecord class belongs to a table with a `user_name` column, you'll have `user_name` and `user_name=` methods without defining them anywhere. The values returned by `user_name` and set by `user_name =` will also not correspond to instance variables. I.e. there will be no instance variable named `@user_name`.

Another way to automatically define `user_name` and `user_name=` without using instance variables is `Struct`:

```
MyClass = Struct.new(:user_name)
```

Here `MyClass` will have the methods `user_name` and `user_name=`, but no instance variable `@user_name` will be set at any point.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome in the "scope" hell!

Of course, if we have the full code, it should be easier to explain what you see.

Let me try:

```
class Woot
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize
    self.name = 'Bistromathic Drive'
  end

  def foo
    puts name # hum… I don't know name. An attr? Oh Yes!
    name = '42' # New local var named 'name'
    puts name # Yeah! I know a local named 'name'
    puts self.name # I know the attr named 'name'
    name = 'Improbability Drive' # Change the local
    puts name 
    puts self.name # attr didn't move
    self.name = 'What was the question?'
    puts name
    puts self.name
  end
end
w = Woot.new
w.foo
# => Bistromathic Drive
42
Bistromathic Drive
Improbability Drive
Bistromathic Drive
Improbability Drive
What was the question?
```

The partial code you show is "suspect" to me, and I'd prefer to explain the base of var scope.